# IEnumerable C# object to JSON object of arrays with name

Tags: c#, json, ienumerable

```
 public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProdcut()
 {
     var products= _productRepository.GetAllProduct();
     return products;
 }
```

The above code returns the following JSON object:

```
[  
    {  
      "$id":"1",
      "Id":1,      
      "Name":"Dave",
      "Department":"IT",
    },
    {  
       "$id":"2",
      "Id":2,      
      "Name":"Dave",
      "Department":"IT",
    },
    {  
      "$id":"3",
      "Id":3,      
      "Name":"Dave",
      "Department":"IT",
    },
    {  
       "$id":"4",
      "Id":4,      
      "Name":"Dave",
      "Department":"IT",
    }
]
```

What I need is to add  `{ "data":` at the beginning  and `}` at the end.

What's the best way to add `{ "data":` at the beginning and `}` at the end?

I don't want to use string concatenation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to return an anonymous object:

```c#
public object GetAllProduct()
{
    var products= _productRepository.GetAllProduct();
    return new { data = products };
}
```

Here is a fiddle demo - https://dotnetfiddle.net/nKRsnQ